# IF condition in Elasticsearch DSL

Tags: python-3.x, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I am new to Elasticsearch and I have an ELS index "**student**" with the following query. I need to execute the **student.name** only when the ****is_rep**=True**.

**Note:** is_rep field will not be available explicitly

```
"query": {
  "bool": {
    "must": { "term": { "subject": "maths" }} ,
    "must": { "term": { "student.name": "xyz"}}
   }
}
```

Can anyone please guide me to achieve this

Comment: What does "will not be available explicitly" mean? That it's not present in every document?

Comment: @JoeSorocin No..i will not know is_rep field's value to add or remove student.name from the query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "subject": "maths"
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "minimum_should_match": 1,
            "should": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "is_rep": false
                }
              },
              {
                "bool": {
                  "filter": [
                    {
                      "term": {
                        "student.name": "xyz"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "term": {
                        "is_rep": true
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```